# Delegated authentication request

Tags: single-sign-on, delegated-authentication

I need to activate delegated authentication for a sandbox. Because I need to test single sign on for mobile devices. Can I request it for a separate sandbox or we need to activate in on production and then we need to refresh our sandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request this to be activated on your sandbox only.